# $f,g$ analytic on $I\subset \mathbb{R}$. If exist $a\in I$ such that $f=g$ and $f^{(n)}=g^{(n)}$then we have $f(x)=g(x)$ for every $x \in I$.

Tags: real-analysis, analyticity, analytic-functions

> **Problem**
>
> Let $f,g$ analytic on an open interval $I\subset \mathbb{R}$. If exist
> some $a\in I$ such that $f(a)=g(a)$ and $f^{(n)}(a)=g^{(n)}(a)$ for
> all $n \in \mathbb{N}$ then we have $f(x)=g(x)$ for every $x \in I$.
>
> Show this is no longer true if you just suppose $f,g$ class $C^\infty
> > $

Well, my idea is just write these series and show that if all terms are the same, these functions well be the same as well. But ***my main problem is understanding this fundamental difference between analytic or $ C^\infty $.***

The core of this problem is being able to write the series of these functions?

Comment: In $C^\infty$ not all Taylor series converge to the function. The function $f(x)=\begin{cases}e^{-1/x^2},&x\neq0\\0,&x=0\end{cases}$ has Taylor series $0$ at $x=0$. But the function is not zero. In this case $f$ and the function $g(x)=0$ would satisfy $f^{(n)}(0)=0=g^{(n)}(0)$ for all $n$.

Comment: By $f=g$ and $f^{(n)}=g^{(n)}$, do you mean $f(a)=g(a)$ and $f^{(n)}(a)=g^{(n)}$? That is, as opposed to the actual meaning of $f=g$, which is: $[\forall x\in I, f(x)=g(x)]$.

Comment: $C^{\infty}$ functions (also called smooth functions) are infinitely differentiable everywhere in their domain. Analytic functions are a subset of the smooth functions where their Taylor series agrees exactly with the function. You can write a Taylor series for any smooth function, but it need not agree with the function everywhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For $C^{\infty}$ but non analytic functions, there is a standard example, that is

$$f(x)=\begin{cases}e^{-\frac{1}{x^2}}\ \ &x\neq 0\\
0\ \ &x=0\end{cases}\\
g(x)=0$$

It is a good exercise to prove that $f(x)$ is $C^\infty$ and that $\forall_ n\ f^{(n)}(0)=0$. Thus we have two different infinitely differentiable  function, equal and with n-th derivative equal in $0$.

Note that, obviously, $f(x)\neq \sum \frac{f^{(n)}(0)}{n!}x^n=0$

This is the fundamental difference between being smooth and being analytic: smooth function can be approximated with an error $O(x^n)$ for any $n$, but this does not mean that the error in the approximation tends to $0$. That condition is only satisfied by analytic functions. 
In our example, the Taylor expantion has an error $\frac{f^{(n+1)}(\zeta)}{(n+1)!}\zeta^{(n+1)}$, and this term does not go to zero, since $f^{(n)}$  grows bigger for every $n$

As a note, it might be useful to observe that actually we have our example is "quite nice", that is our function is non analytic only in $0$. There are some functions (like the [Fabius function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fabius_function?wprov=sfla1)) which are smooth but nowhere analytic. The math behind those example is quite hard though.

Comment: Thank you very much for your explanation.